# Stale Element Reference Exception- Trying to change value of a drop down after refresh

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am working on 3 drop downs where value of first and third drop down is constant and I have to change the value for second drop down and on the basis of this change I get coordinates  of the stores on the web page. I am keeping first and third drop down constant and changing the value of second drop down using for loop. Although value is changing but co ordinates on the web page are not changing. Values of co ordinates on the page remain same as for first selection. Below is the piece of code I have written

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "D:\\SELONew\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

     driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.navigate().to("http://www.motherdairy.com/StoreLocator");

    // ****************** Selecting State Drop Down



    Select stateDropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By
            .xpath(".//*[@id='drpState']")));


    stateDropDown.selectByVisibleText("Delhi");


    // ******************* Selecting City Drop Down

    Select cityDropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("drpCity")));

    int citydrpdwnsize = cityDropDown.getOptions().size();

    for (int i = 1; i <= citydrpdwnsize; i++) {

        cityDropDown.selectByIndex(i);

        Select product = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("drpBrand")));

        product.selectByVisibleText("Mother Dairy");

        int s = driver
                .findElements(
                        By.xpath(".//div[@id='storeLocator']//a[text()='Locate Us']"))
                .size();
        System.out.println(s);

        driver.navigate().refresh();

        stateDropDown.selectByVisibleText("Delhi");
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which line do you get it?

Comment: Value of  stores co-ordinates should change for each selection of second drop down.  In my code I am trying to count the number stores using below line  int s = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@id='storeLocator']//a[text()='Locate Us']")).size();               So here drop down value is changing but stores co-ordinates remain same

Comment: This is how it should work, you need to find the element again after the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Separating it all into fields and methods should be the right thing to do.
Not sure why you need to refresh the site, but with it it should go like that:

```
public class TestClass {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static WebDriverWait wait;

    @FindBy(id = "drpState")
    private WebElement stateDropDown;

    @FindBy(id = "drpCity")
    private WebElement cityDropDown;

    @FindBy(id = "drpBrand")
    private WebElement brandDropDown;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "D:\\SELONew\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.motherdairy.com/StoreLocator");
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        // ****************** Selecting State Drop Down
        selectTextFromDropDown(stateDropDown, "Delhi");
        // ******************* Selecting City Drop Down
        waitForListToHaveEnoughElements(cityDropDown, 1);
        int cityDropDownSize = getOptionsFromDropDown(cityDropDown).size();
        for (int i = 0; i < cityDropDownSize; i++) {
            new Select(cityDropDown).selectByIndex(i);
            selectTextFromDropDown(brandDropDown, "Mother Dairy");
            int size = driver
                    .findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@id='storeLocator']//a[text()='Locate Us']"))
                    .size();
            System.out.println(size);
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            //Initialize all elements one more time:
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(stateDropDown));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(cityDropDown));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(brandDropDown));
            selectTextFromDropDown(stateDropDown, "Delhi");
            waitForListToHaveEnoughElements(cityDropDown, 1);
            //It is a good place for some assertions.
        }
    }

    private void selectTextFromDropDown(WebElement forSelect, String text) {
        Select select = new Select(forSelect);
        select.selectByVisibleText(text);
    }

    private List<WebElement> getOptionsFromDropDown(WebElement forSelect) {
        return new Select(forSelect).getOptions();
    }

    private void waitForListToHaveEnoughElements(WebElement forList, int size) {
        wait.until((Predicate<WebDriver>) driver -> {
            List<WebElement> options = getOptionsFromDropDown(forList);
            return options.size() > size;
        });
    }
}
```

The next step would be to separate test logic from the page object.